# Nested alignment of grouped equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath, nesting

I want a collection of equations to be aligned as a whole, yet subgroups of them given descriptions. What follow are two attempts, each which achieve exactly one of the requirements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Comments are centred on groups, but equations are not globally horizontally
aligned:
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
    \begin{aligned}
      f(xy) &= f(x)f(y)\\
      f(1) &= 1
    \end{aligned} &\qquad{\text{(Algebra map)}}\\
    \begin{aligned}
      \Delta f (x) &=  (f\otimes f) (\Delta x)\\
      \epsilon f(x) &= \epsilon x
    \end{aligned} & \qquad{\text{(Coalgebra map)}}\\
    \begin{aligned}
      f(Sx) &= Sf(x)
    \end{aligned} & \qquad{\text{(Antipode compatibility)}}
  \end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

Equalities are horizontally aligned, but comments are not vertically aligned to
the centre of the group they describe, nor are horizontally left-justified with each other:
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    f(xy) &= f(x)f(y)\\
      f(1) &= 1\qquad\qquad{\text{(Algebra map)}}\\
    \Delta f (x) &= f\otimes f (\Delta x)\\
    \epsilon f(x) &= \epsilon x\qquad\qquad{\text{(Coalgebra map)}}\\
    f(Sx) &= Sf(x) \qquad{\text{(Antipode compatibility)}}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

The use of `\qquad` here is rather ad-hoc, but provides a modicum of separation in the second example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this?

[image]

used are `align` and `split` environments from the package `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    \begin{split}
      f(xy) &= f(x)f(y)\\
      f(1)  &= 1
    \end{split}     &&  \text{(Algebra map)}    \\[\jot]
    \begin{split}
      \Delta f (x)  &=  (f\otimes f) (\Delta x) \\
      \epsilon f(x) &= \epsilon x
    \end{split}     &&  \text{(Coalgebra map)}  \\[\jot]
      f(Sx) &= Sf(x)&&  \text{(Antipode compatibility)}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**   the three groups of conditions are now separated for vertical size of `\jot` as suggested [GuM](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/69818/gum) in his comment below.

Comment: (+1)  It’s a matter of personal taste, but I’d also separate the three groups of conditions by means of `\\[\jot]`.

Comment: The last equation (`f(Sx) &=Sf(x)`) appears not to need the split environment. Is there a reason to keep it?

Comment: @GuM, from what I understand, `\jot` determines the spacing in a multiline environment, yet `\\` and `\\[\jot]` are producing different results. What is the spacing given by a newline with no arguments?

Comment: @Phrohlych, in last equation the `split`  is superfluous. i remove it now.  `\jot` here is used as measure for vertical distance and had to be used as it is used in answer.

Comment: @Zarko Is the (default) definition of `\\jot` a space slightly larger than the (default) space between equations in a multiline environment, then?

Comment: @Phrohlych, it should not be. however, instead `\\[\jot]` you can use for example `\\[1ex]`. it gives approximately equal vertical distance between equations as . if you like to have bigger distance, accordingly change `\[1ex]` to for example `\\[2ex]`.